# How to hide the tab bar navigation header in xamarin forms ios

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, tabbedpage

I have an application with 8 tab bar, am using custom navigation bar for all pages.In ios while clicking the item from the more tab, the tab bar title is coming as navigation bar header, how to hide that navigation bar header.

I have added the below code in TabbedPage and Page1 Xaml pages. It is working for upto 4 tabs. But when clicks on more tab item , header is coming.

```
NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar=False;
NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False";
```

Here is the code I used for adding tabbed pages.

```
public TabbedPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       
        for(int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
        {
            Page _page = null;
            _page = new Page1();
            _page.Title = "Class" + i.ToString();
            Children.Add(_page);

        }
    }
```

[image: This is the]

I want to remove the Class 7 heading and need to place the heading after the navigation bar.

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot? it will be helpful to better understand the question. Is it the same thing with Shell ?

Comment: @Cfun screenshot added.

Answer (score 0):

Don't place `TabbedPage` inside `NavigationPage` , it's not a good design.

**Correct way** : set `TabbedPage` as `MainPage` and wrap the children pages inside `NavigationPage`.

#### App

```
public App()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   //MainPage = new NavigationPage( new TabbedPage1());  //don't use this way

   MainPage = new TabbedPage1();
}
```

#### TabbedPage

```
public TabbedPage1()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
   {      
     Page _page = null;
     _page = new Page1();
     _page.Title = "Class" + i.ToString();

     NavigationPage navi = new NavigationPage(_page);
     navi.Title = "Page" + i.ToString();
     Children.Add(navi);

   }
}
```